# vector error correction model results

Tags: regression-coefficients, cointegration, vector-error-correction-model, granger-causality, eviews

[image]

First i checked the cointegration using Johansen. After that i estimated a VECM model using both b_r and b_f as the left hand variable and it gave me different results. the error correction term are also not significant for both equation in b_r as the left hand variable. however, when i put b_f as the left hand variable it kinda give me better results cause the first equation is now significant altho the other one is still isn't. so how do i interpret this?

[image: This is for the b_f as the left hand variable results]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: im checking the cointegration between farmgate (b_f) and retail (b_r) price of beef. both are stationary at first difference and johansen test indicated me that there is a cointegration at lag 1. granger causality test shows that b_r granger cause b_f

Comment: What do you mean by *After that i estimated a VECM model using both b_r and b_f as the left hand variable and it gave me different results*? If you used b_r as a dependent variable first and then b_f as a dependent variable after that, why should they ever yield the same result?

Comment: I am referring to the significance of error correction term. Using b_r as the dependent variable gave me a non significant ect while using b_f as the dependent variable gave me a significant ect. I assumed both should be significant because the variables are cointegerated.